# Hide animation on menu doesn't apply to all its children

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

As you can see in the snippet below, when I click on the menu icon the show / hide animation is done correctly but this is not applied to the contents of the items.

Moreover, when the class 'active-menu' is attached to the menu, the 'item' class correctly apply the display: grid property, but as soon as it closes the content of the items behaves like it is not considered anymore as a direct son of the menu but directly of the container, which is wrong.

I can not clearly tell where the problem is, so I need your advice (I hope I was clear in the explanation)

```js
let topBar = document.getElementById("tobBar");
let menu = document.getElementById("menu");

ico.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    ico.classList.toggle("toggle-color");
    menu.classList.toggle("active-menu");
})
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.container {
    width: 370px;
    height: 550px;
    background: darkgray;
    z-index: -2;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

/*  *   * TOP BAR  *   *   */

.top-bar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background:  #00b0ff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 999;
    border-top-left-radius: inherit;
    border-top-right-radius: inherit;
}

.top-bar-ico {
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999;
}

.toggle-color {
    color: white;
}

/*  *   *   *   *   */

/*  *   *  MENU *   *   */

.menu {
    height: 500px;
    transition: 0.5s linear;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.active-menu {
    width: 90%;
    background:  #00b0ff;
    z-index: 999;
    border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;
}

.active-menu > * {
    background-color: white;
}

/*  *   *   *   *   */


/*  *   * MENU ITEMS  *   *   */

.menu > .item {
    height: 50px;
}

.item:not(:first-child)  {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr;
    grid-gap: 5px;
}

/*  *   *   *   *   */
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-bar">
        <div id="ico" class="top-bar-ico">
            <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="top-bar-title">
            <p>Click the icon</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu" class="menu">
        <div id="menuItem" class="item">
            <div class="item-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="item-title">
                Menu item
            </div>
            <div class="item-text">
                lalalala
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `overflow:hidden` to `.menu`. See below:

```js
let topBar = document.getElementById("tobBar");
let menu = document.getElementById("menu");

ico.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  ico.classList.toggle("toggle-color");
  menu.classList.toggle("active-menu");
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.container {
  width: 370px;
  height: 550px;
  background: darkgray;
  z-index: -2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
}


/*  *   * TOP BAR  *   *   */

.top-bar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00b0ff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 999;
  border-top-left-radius: inherit;
  border-top-right-radius: inherit;
}

.top-bar-ico {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 999;
}

.toggle-color {
  color: white;
}


/*  *   *   *   *   */


/*  *   *  MENU *   *   */

.menu {
  height: 500px;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.active-menu {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: #00b0ff;
  z-index: 999;
  border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;
}

.active-menu>* {
  background-color: white;
}


/*  *   *   *   *   */


/*  *   * MENU ITEMS  *   *   */

.menu>.item {
  height: 50px;
}

.item:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}


/*  *   *   *   *   */
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top-bar">
      <div id="ico" class="top-bar-ico">
        <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="top-bar-title">
        <p>Click the icon</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu" class="menu">
      <div id="menuItem" class="item">
        <div class="item-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title">
          Menu item
        </div>
        <div class="item-text">
          lalalala
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```